# Laurent expansion in annular region

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I can't understand why my solution to this exercise is conceptually wrong... can you help me?

> Laurent expansion of $$f(z)=\frac{z^2+2}{z^3-3z^2+2z}$$
>
> in 1<|z|<2

My solution:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{3}{z-2}-\frac{3}{z-1}$$

$$f_1=\frac{1}{z}$$
$$f_2=\frac{3}{z-2}=\frac{3}{-2[1-\frac{z}{2}]}=-(3/2) \sum_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{2})^n$$
$$f_3=\frac{3}{z-1}=-3\sum_0^{\infty}(z)^n$$

so

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}-(3/2) \sum_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{2})^n+3\sum_{0}^{\infty}(z)^n$$

but the correct solution seems to be

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}-(3/2) \sum_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{2})^n-3\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Your "solution" is *obviously* not correct because it is **analytic** at both 1 and 2 while the given function is not.

Comment: @user247327 can you explain me more?

Comment: @user247327 1 is not in the annular region... why do I have to treat it as if it was inside it?

Answer (score 1):

It is "conceptually wrong" only in $f_3$ part. Your series expansion diverges for $|z|>1$. You need to use powers of $z^{-1}$ instead 
$$
f_3(z)=\frac{3}{z-1}=\frac{3}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}=\frac{3}{z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{-k}.
$$

Comment: Because the analytical part of the espansion must be analytical in any point inside the "larger" region, not only inside the annular region... am I wrong? http://imageshack.com/a/img922/6370/XS7bvW.png (sorry for the horrible sketch :D )

Comment: @sunrise it is true. The function $f_2$ has pole at $z=2$ and is analytical in $|z|<2$, the functions $f_1$ and $f_3$ with poles at $z=0$, resp. $z=1$, are analytical in $|z|>1$. The function $f_3$ is also analytical in $|z|<1$, and you have found the correct power expansion of $f_3$ there, but it is a **wrong region**.